# How to set a default value for an EntityType / <select> element in a symfony form?

Tags: symfony, twig

How to set value in select on twig?
When I submit my form one of the value is null and when dump in the controller show me null.

```php
$builder
    ->add('date', null, [
        'widget' => 'single_text'
    ])
    ->add('hairstyle',EntityType::class,[
        'class' => Hairstyle::class,
        'mapped' => false,
    ])
;
```

I add in twig this:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
  {{ form_widget(form.hairstyle, {value: Setcountry ~ "" } ) }}
{{ form_errors(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

This is my `var_dump` in controller:

```
 private 'normData' => object(BeautySalonBundle\Entity\Reservation)[824]
   private 'id' => null
   private 'date' => object(DateTime)[1034]
     public 'date' => string '2020-02-21 21:21:00.000000' (length=26)
     public 'timezone_type' => int 3
   private 'hairstyle' => null
   private 'user' => null
 private 'viewData' =>
```

Comment: have you tried removing ```'mapped' => false``` from the formbuilder?

Answer (score -1):

You can leverage the `empty_data` option to provide a default entity for your `EntityType` select-field of type `Hairstyle`.

- Inject the repository into your form type
- Use the repository in a closure for the `empty_data` option
- Fetch and return the default entity from the repository inside the closure

```php
class YourFormType extends AbstractType
{
  private const DEFAULT_HAIRSTYLE_ID = 1;

  /** @var HairstyleRepository */
  private $hairstyleRepository;

  public function __construct(HairstyleRepository $hairstyleRepository)
  {
     $this->hairstyleRepository = $hairstyleRepository;
  }

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    // create an intermediate variable for use in the closure
    $hairstyleRepository = $this->hairstyleRepository;

    $builder
      // ..
      ->add('hairstyle', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => Hairstyle::class,
        // return a default Hairstyle entity
        'empty_data' => function(FormInterface $form) use ($hairstyleRepository) {
          return $hairstyleRepository->getOneById(self::DEFAULT_HAIRSTYLE_ID);
        },
      ])
  }
```